# When trying to create an inverted Mandelbrot-set it's distorted

Tags: java, processing, complex-numbers, fractals, mandelbrot

When I make a normal Mandelbrot set, it works fine. But when I try to invert it into a teardrop-like thing (see here for more context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLJJUElQMRY) it is completely distorted and looks nothing like a teardrop.

I've tried looking into it but it seems like I'm doing everything correct. I'm inverting it by dividing 1 by the 'c' variable.

Here is a section of my code which is the actual formula, this is written in processing which is just Java with added visual libraries:

```java
zx2=zx*zx;
zy2=zy*zy;
zy = 2*zx*zy + 1.0/(y); //the "1.0/" is what makes it inverted, a normal Mandelbrot set is just y and x on its own.
zx = zx2-zy2 + 1.0/(x);
```

It's extremely distorted when I run the code and doesn't even look like a teardrop! Here is what it looks like:

[image: Distorted looking image]

Then I tried fixing it by implementing the code of an answer, here's the code:

```
zx2=zx*zx;
zy2=zy*zy;
zy = 2*zx*zy + (y/(x*x+y*y));
zx = zx2-zy2 + (x/(x*s+y*y));
```

But although it does look inverted, it's still distorted and doesn't look like a teardrop. Here's a photo:

[image: Distorted Inverted Mandelbrot].

Have I done something wrong while implementing the code?

Comment: Why do you think that your formulas should make the inverted mandelbrot? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Yunnosch The 1.0/y and the 1.0/x are what makes it inverted, a normal Mandelbrot set has just y and x on its own.

Comment: That is not the same as the expression shown [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02341047).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to think of `c` as a complex number, so in the normal Mandelbrot case, we have:

```
zy = 2*zx * zy + cy;
zx = zx2 - zy2 + cx;
```

But to get the reciprocal of `c`, we have to do a *complex* reciprocal:

```
zy = 2*zx * zy + (cy / (cx**2 + cy**2));
zx = zx2 - zy2 + (cx / (cx**2 + cy**2));
```

Of course, since `c` is constant from the loop's prespective, we can calculate the reciprocal before the loop.  In a language like Python with complex numbers, it's a simple change from normal Mandelbrot:

```
c = complex(real, imaginary)

z = 0j

for i in range(iterations):
    if abs(z) >= 4.0:
        break

    z = z * z + c
```

to inverted Mandelbrot:

```
c = 1 / complex(real, imaginary)

z = 0j

for i in range(iterations):
    # ...
```

But if we're implementing the complex numbers ourselves, then for the normal Mandelbrot we do:

```
x = real
y = imaginary

zx = 0
zy = 0

for i in range(iterations):
    zx2 = zx * zx
    zy2 = zy * zy

    if ((zx2 + zy2) ** 0.5) >= 4.0:
        break

    zy = 2*zx * zy + y
    zx = zx2 - zy2 + x
```

and for the inverted Mandelbrot we do:

```
denominator = real**2 + imaginary**2

x = real / denominator
y = imaginary / denominator

zx = 0
zy = 0

for i in range(iterations):
    # ...
```

Bottom line, it's the difference between:

```
1 / complex(real, imaginary)  # correct
```

and:

```
complex(1 / real, 1 / imaginary)  # incorrect
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But after implementing your code, it does look inverted by is still distorted and doesn't look like a teardrop, here it is: https://imgur.com/x7Z4K8p.

Comment: @MorganS42, your updated code has the term `x/(x*s+y*y)` instead of `x/(x*x+y*y)` -- if that's not the cause of the current problem, provide more of your source code.

Comment: that was completly it! Thanks so much for all your help, I can't believe I didn't notice that earlier, silly me.

Comment: Do you also think you could include some sources to how you were able to convert a complex equation to an equation using x and y (representing real and imaginary numbers)? Thanks.